# GLSL Core Functionality Geometry Shader examples

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm doing some research on geometry shaders and am having problems finding code examples/tutorials that does not use one of the extensions introduced before it was core functionality of OpenGL 3.2.

I'm looking for more modern approaches that doesn't use an extension.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I've already read the spec, but am looking for actually code examples.

Answer (score 4):

My tutorial on impostors has an [example of using core geometry shaders](https://nicolbolas.github.io/oldtut/Illumination/Tut13%20Purloined%20Primitives.html). GS's aren't really the most useful things in the world, so it's hard to find legitimate examples. Indeed, the only future tutorial I have planned that uses them is for layered rendering for things like rendering to cube-maps.

Comment: I'm actually fixing to try and use geometry shader for rending a cube map.